# java.lang.NullPointerException with a custom class in Processing

Tags: java, processing

Alright, I am a newbie at programming so I don't have the basics very clear (also my english is pretty bad). When I started this code, I wanted it to draw some points, keep them moving and if they were closer than X between them, then draw a line. But I wanted to make it a little bit more complicated and then add another class, which was intended to dont interact with the other class and draw a circle and some next to it, constrained within a rectangle (I tried to constrain them to a circle but... too much for my head for now). Well, the thing is that I think that the code is ""clear"", at least for the PC, and I don't know why am I getting this "java.lang.NullPointerException" error, because it doesn't show me where the error is.

Any help will be very appreciated.

```
//Test nº1. An array of spheres which are randomly moving, connected between them if the distance is less than 50p.
//The spheres' starting position are determined by the red(x) and green(y) color space from colordata from images.


int[] tots = {#2d2a33, #8e8397, #160e19, #8263a9, #0f1723, #737a86, #2d2a33, #8e8497, #15101c, #965555, #1a2940, #9b7873, #080b12, #272b41, #211f33, #8b6659,
            #070719, #4c5985, #423444, #9c8696, #1a2d13, #799078, #30160e, #da9c7b, #2c2e3a, #6d798e, #28474f, #b63f10, #040c1a, #cf6c24, #442036, #a87d99,
            #19191a, #756d6e, #1a2828, #94b1a2, #060c15, #6d98c1, #284062, #9ab9be, #121720, #abb7c5, #6e6b9b, #282033};

//--Malla--

float xo, yo;

int numMalla = 200;

Malla[] ma = new Malla [numMalla]; 

float x;
float y;
float angle = 0.0; // Direction of motion  
//float speed = random(0.2, 0.8); // Speed of motion

float diameter = 0.0;

//----

//--Errant--

int numPiEr = 10;
int e;

float xoEr = width/2;
float yoEr = height/2;
float xoPiEr = xoEr;
float yoPiEr = yoEr;
float cRotO = 0;

Errant ccEr;
//Errant clEr;
Errant[] piEr = new Errant [numPiEr];
//----

void setup() {
//--Malla--
//coords mapping into the original position
xo = map( (tots[int(random(0,tots.length))]& 0xFF0000)>>16, 0, 255, 0, width);
yo = map( (tots[int(random(0,tots.length))]& 0x00FF00)>>8, 0, 255, 0, height);
//----  

size(1024, 768,P2D);
background(0);
smooth();
frameRate(25);
//float rad = random(5.0,150.0);

//--Malla--
for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
ma[i] = new Malla(random(10,width-10),random(10,height-10),angle);

}
//----
//--Errant--

Errant ccEr = new Errant (xoEr, yoEr, cRotO);
//Errant clEr = new Errant (xoEr, yoEr, cRotO);

for (int e = 0; e < piEr.length; e++) {
  piEr[e] = new Errant(xoPiEr, yoPiEr, cRotO);
}

//----

}


void draw() {

  background(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
    ma[i].maMove();
    for (int j = i + 1; j < ma.length; j++) {
      if (ma[i].nearAnotherMalla(ma[j])) {
        ma[i].highlight();
      }
    }
    ma[i].display();
  } 

  for (int e = 0; e < piEr.length; e++) {
    piEr[e].piErMove();
    piEr[e].piErDisplay();

  }
  ccEr.erMove();
  ccEr.errDisplay();
}



class Malla {

float x,y;
float diameter;
float speedX, speedY;
float angle;
//int temps;
//color c = color(255);
Malla[] nearMalla = new Malla[numMalla];

//----

  Malla(float xpos, float ypos, float dir) {

  xo = x;
  yo = y;

  x = xpos;
  y = ypos;
  //speedX = random(-0.2, 0.2);
  //speedY = random(-0.2, 0.2);
  speedX = random(-2, 2);
  speedY = random(-2, 2);
  //temps=0;
  //diameter = random(5, 13);
  diameter = 2.5;
  angle = dir;

}

//----

void maMove() {

 /*  if(temps==10){
  speedX = random(-2, 2);
  speedY = random(-2, 2);
  temps=0;
   }
   ++temps;*/

   if(x+diameter >= width+20) {
      speedX = -speedX;
    }  
    else if(x+diameter <= -20) {
      speedX = -speedX;
    }

    if(y+diameter >= height+20) {
      speedY = -speedY;  
    }
    else if(y+diameter <= -20) {
       speedY = -speedY;
    }

    // angle += random(-0.13, 0.13);
/* x += speedX;
 y += speedY;*/

     angle += random(-0.13, 0.13);

    x += cos(angle) * speedX;
    y += sin(angle) * speedY; 
}

//----

void highlight() {
  //c = color(255,100);
  stroke(255,1);
  for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
  if (nearMalla[i] != null) {

    line(x, y, nearMalla[i].x, nearMalla[i].y);
  }
}
 }

//----

void display() {
  //stroke(c);
  noStroke();
  //noFill();
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x,y,diameter,diameter);
  //c = color(0);
}

//----

 boolean nearAnotherMalla(Malla b) {
   boolean near = dist(x,y,b.x,b.y) <= 60;
    for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
   if (near) {
       nearMalla[i] = b;
   } 
   else {
     nearMalla[i] = null;
   }
   }
   return near;

 }
}
```

This is what doesn't work, the single object

```
class Errant {

  float xEr, yEr, xPiEr, yPiEr, cRot, velEr, velErX, velErY, velPiEr,  velPiErX, velPiErY;
  int ccDiam, clDiamX, clDiamY, piErDiam;


  Errant[] nearPiEr = new Errant[numPiEr];

  //----

  Errant(float xEr, float yEr, float cRot) {

    ccDiam = 15;
    clDiamX = 80;
    clDiamY = 70;

    xEr = xoEr;
    yEr = yoEr;

    xPiEr = random((xEr-20),(xEr+20));
    yPiEr= random((yEr-20), (yEr+20));

    cRot = cRotO;

    velEr = random(-3,3);
    velEr = velErX = velErY;
    velPiEr = random(-1.5,1.5);
    velPiEr = velPiErX = velPiErY;
  }


  void erMove() {

    if(xEr+clDiamX >= width+100) {
      velErX = -velErX;
    }  
    else if(xEr+clDiamX <= -100) {
      velErX = -velErX;
    }

    if(yEr+clDiamX >= height+100) {
      velErY = -velErY;  
    }
    else if(yEr+clDiamX <= -100) {
       velErY = -velErY;
    }

    cRot += random(-0.2,0.2);
    xEr = cos(cRot)*velEr;
    yEr = sin(cRot)*velEr;

  }

  void piErMove() {

    if(xPiEr >= xEr+clDiamX) {
      velErX = -velPiErX;
    }  
    else if(xPiEr <= xEr-clDiamX) {
      velErX = -velPiErX;
    }

    if(yPiEr >= yEr+clDiamY) {
      velErY = -velPiErY;  
    }
    else if(yPiEr <= xEr-clDiamY) {
       velErY = -velPiErY;
    }

    xPiEr = cos(cRot)*velPiEr;
    yPiEr = sin(cRot)*velPiEr;

  }

  void errDisplay () {
    noStroke();
    fill(#EFE4B0, 70);

    ellipse(xEr, yEr, 10, 10);
  }

  void piErDisplay () {
    fill(#EFC6B0, 50);

    ellipse(xPiEr, yPiEr, 1, 1);
  }

}
```

---

Thanks in advance, girald0.

This is the error message that I get in the console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
    at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
    at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:206)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:172)
    at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:191)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:541)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL.requestDraw(PJOGL.java:688)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1651)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at punts_moviment_mapejats2.draw(punts_moviment_mapejats2.java:111)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When you post a question that pertains to an error, please include your stack trace listing the exact error message.

Comment: Okay, I edited with the error messages in the console

Comment: And to which line of your code does this error refer? 'at punts_moviment_mapejats2.draw(punts_moviment_mapejats2.java:111)' Which line is 111?

Comment: I have the custom classes in separate tabs, so following the natural order I think the line nº111 is " clDiamX = 80; "

Comment: NullPointerException occurs when you attempt to refer to an object which does not exist (i.e. it's null). Look at your error message again. It *tells* you the class where the error occurs: punts_moviment_mapejats2. What is line 111 from punts_moviment_mapejats2?

Comment: there is no line 111 from punts_moviment_mapejats2, the last line is the number 97 :/

Comment: Your stack trace says otherwise. You're using some sort of editor or IDE that numbers your lines, right, and that's where you're looking at line numbers (as opposed to counting them manually), yes? Also, if you've been monkeying with your code and deleting lines, naturally the line numbers will change. Run the code again and get the *latest* error message.

Comment: It's I'm afraid not easy to extract the exact line like that. Processing is a very simple IDE that attaches code at the top of your Java classes. Thus the stack traces refer to the modified version, not the one you are seeing in Processing. In order to do that, you have to export the app and then look into the actual .java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing runs the sketch() method first and the draw() method continuously after that. If you don't want to dig into the actual .java source code as per my comment to your question you can just start commenting stuff in setup and draw until your sketch runs again, which will point to the offending line.

The problem seems to be line 94:

```
ccEr.erMove();
```

with ccEr being null.

You define this variable twice, once on line 37:

```
Errant ccEr;
```

and once more on line 63:

```
Errant ccEr = new Errant (xoEr, yoEr, cRotO);
```

Processing seems to only take into account only the first (line 37), and in the that one you don't actually create the object, just a variable called ccEr with nothing inside it (null if you prefer)

Now, I commented line 37 and then it couldn't find the variable at all! This is perplexing to me, as I was aware you could define "global" variables everywhere. Apparently the internal hocus-pocus of Processing has changed and thus you have to transfer line 63 (where you define and create ccEr) above setup()...

Comment: Thank you Petros, I moved the line 63 above setup and now the sketch runs without errors. I don't get the Errant class displayed(my code is very confusing I think), but I think I will be able to manage it by myself. Again, thanks.